# Program to create patterns of different sizes, and theres some confusion

Tags: c++, loops, design-patterns

I would really appreciate some help on this code I'm writing. The goal of my program is to be able to create 4 different patterns of varying sizes. The size of each pattern is determined by the number of columns or rows. For example, a pattern of size 5 has 5 columns and 5 rows. Each pattern is made of the character * and a digit which shows the size. The size must be between 2 and 9.
these are the patterns:
Pattern 1:

```
*5555
5*555
55*55
555*5
5555*
```

Pattern 2:

```
*****
*555*
*555*
*555*
*****
```

Pattern 3:

```
55555
5***5
5***5
5***5
55555
```

Pattern 4:

```
5555*
555*5
55*55
5*555
*5555
```

My program must display a menu and ask the user to choose a pattern and size. I must have separate functions to get the option, get the size, and to print each of pattern.

Here is what I have so far for my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void showmenu();
double Get_option ();
double Get_size ();
void pattern1 (int);
void pattern2 (int);
void pattern3 (int);
void pattern4 (int);

int main ()

{
    int size1, option1;
    const int pattern_1 = 1,
    pattern_2 = 2,
    pattern_3 = 3,
    pattern_4 = 4,
    quit = 5;


    do
    {
        showmenu ();

        option1 = Get_option ();

        size1 = Get_size ();

        if (option1 != quit)
        {
            switch (option1)
            { 
            case 1:
                pattern1 (size1);
                break;
            case 2:
                pattern2 (size1);
                break;
            case 3:
                pattern3 (size1);
                break;
            case 4:
                pattern4 (size1);
                break;
            case 5:
                exit (1);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
    while (option1 != quit);
    return 0;
}

void showmenu ()
{
    printf ("\n\t\t MENU \n\n" );
    printf ( "1. Pattern One" );
    printf ( "2. Pattern Two" );
    printf ( "3. Pattern Three" );
    printf ( "4. Pattern Four" );
    printf ( "Quit \n\n" );

}

double Get_option ()
{ 
    int option;

    printf ("enter option (1-5):");
    scanf ("%d", &option);

    while (option < 1 || option > 5)
    {
        printf ("incorrect option. Try again");
        printf ("Enter option (1-5):");
        scanf ("%d", &option);

    }
    return option;

}

double Get_size ()

{
    int size;

    printf ("Enter pattern size (2-9):");
    scanf ("%d", &size);

    while (size < 2 || size > 9);
    {
        printf ("Incorrect pattern size. Try again");
        printf ("Enter pattern size (2-9):");
        scanf ("%d", &size);

    }

    return size;


}

void pattern1 (int size1)
{
    int row, col;

    for (row = 0; row < size1; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < size1; col++)
        {
            if (row == col)
                printf ("*");
            else
                printf ("%c", size);
                printf ("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a little confused about how to get the other patterns. And if you read this far I really appreciate it. Also I get an error at the case saying "Error: Case label does not reduce to an integer constant"

I really appreciate any help you can get me. I am a beginner on this and I'm not really sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any error about case label, so it might depend on your compiler. `const int` should be enough (I think). If you are still getting this error, consider using an `enum` instead of the const ints, or possibly even just using the number directly in your case statement.

```
case 1:
     pattern1 (size1);
     break;
```

would look OK to me. Especially as you have hard coded the numbers in your prompts anyway.

Other issues you have:

- Don't use `double` as the return value from Get_Option and Get_Size. You should have been getting warnings about loss of precision when converting `int` and back. `int` is fine for these functions.
- Your `printf` call in `pattern1` uses `%c` which will print a control character. Use `%d` to print a number.
- You have a semicolon on the end of your `while` statement checking for size. This means it always asks you twice and doesn't actually check if you entered an invalid size.

As to printing the other patterns, just try to work out how you would do them by hand, write that down as steps (pseudo code), then convert that to c. For example pattern 2 could be.

```
Print N stars
Print a new line
for N - 2 times:
  Print one star
  Print N, N - 2 times
  Print one star
Print a new line
Print N stars
Print a new line
```